# Does MongoDB support XOR (exclusive OR)?

Tags: mongodb

I am looking for a way to do exclusive OR on MongoDB.

For instance, `$or` works as expected:

```
> db.mycollection.find({ '$or': [ { 'a': 1 }, { 'b': 1 } ] })
```

But I would need to find records where `a` is 1 or `b` is 1, but not both of them. Something like this:

```
> db.mycollection.find({ '$xor': [ { 'a': 1 }, { 'b': 1 } ] })
```

(doesn't work - fictional syntax)

Does MongoDB support XOR logical operator? If not, how can it best be simulated?

Comment: good question, looking for the best answer now...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Does this satisfy your expectation?

```
db.mycollection.find({ '$or': [ { 'a': 1 , 'b' : {$ne : 1} }, { 'b': 1, 'a' : {$ne : 1} } ] })
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is hidden behind the [$bit](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/bit/#up._S_bit) name (only for **2.6.x**) but it is **not the xor you want** (it is bitwise xor): `{ $bit: { <field>: { xor: <int> } } }` and used for updates, not for find.

For your case I would use either [$where](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/):

```
db.mycollection.find( { $where: "this.a ^ this.b" } );
```

Or prepopulate my collection with already calculated xor value (to be able to use indexes).